# How do I change array dimensions from one dimension to a two dimension with one column

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to change the shape of a `numpy array` from this...

```
[ 3803.74060338   2041.36742598   2884.96439427  17561.9569717 ]
```

to this...

```
[ [3803.74060338]   
  [2041.36742598]   
  [2884.96439427]  
  [17561.9569717] ]
```

I was trying `np.reshape(my_array, (1,1))` but I keep getting this error...

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Is `reshape` what I want to do here?

Comment: `reshape` with a shape of `(1, 1)` means you want a 1 by 1 output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice with `numpy.newaxis` to put additional axes into the shape of an array:

```
>>> my_array = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> my_array[:, numpy.newaxis]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

(`numpy.newaxis` is `None`, so you can also just use `None` directly. I find `newaxis` more readable, but it's a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: I think that is still slightly different than the result OP is looking for. Your result is a 2D array, but only the first *row* is populated. I think they want a 2D array with only the first *column* populated. You might want to tack an `array.transpose()` on the end of your code.

Comment: That's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The reasons `np.shape()` didn't work was because you are reshaping a 4 element array into a 1 x 1.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.reshape(len(a),1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
>>>
```

Comment: You can use `a.reshape(-1,1)` to let numpy figure out the length automatically (`-1` acts as a joker here)